# Cannot understand this php parser error

Tags: php

Why does this give me parse error? going crazy over here..

I have this file right:

```
function start_connection() {

 global $config['db_host'];

}
```

Parse error: parse error, expecting `','' or`';'' in functions.php on line 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't global an array within a variable. Only the variable.

Answer (score 8):

when declaring the global variable do not include the array key, so:

```
global $config;
```

this will provide access to all key => value pairs within $config array within the function start_connection().

Answer (score 1):

just do:

```
function start_connection() {
 global $config;
 echo $config['db_host'];
}
```

You can only use global variables, but not a specific value of a array.